# Couchbase SDK 3.x Spring data cache

Tags: java, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

Whats the recommended way to create CouchBaseCacheManager instance using default Couchbase Collection ? Couldn't find a good code example or description on the web.

Comment: Do you know how to specify the collection name? If so, you can use the name "_default" to refer to the default collection. If not, please reply and we can dig deeper.